# Convert Short? to System.Collection.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a variable called **filter** being passed into the **SaleList** from the view. When it first loads its always NULL which is should be. I seem to be having an issue with the else statement k = filter. I have tried a couple things which no such luck. Any help would be appreciated .

Cannot implicitly convert type short?[]' to System.Collection.Generic.List

I am not sure how convert this

```
short? filter = sale.SalesStatusID;

List<short> k;

if (filter == null)
{
    k = (from s in _db.SalesStatus
        select s.SaleStatusID).ToList();
}
else
{
    k = filter;
}

var sales = from t in _db.Sales
    where k.Contains((short) t.SalesStatusID)
    select t;
```

Comment: `k` is declared as type `List<short>` - but `filter` is a nullable `short`, not a `List<short>`. Look into [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type short?[]' to System.Collection.Generic.List` Are you 100% sure that is your **exact** error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `k` is a collection of `short` and your `filter` variable is a nullable short. You cannot assign a nullable short(singlet item) to a collection type.

You can create a collection using your filter variable value and assign it.

```
List<short> k;
if (filter != null)
{
    k = new List<short> { filter.Value };
}
else
{
   k = new List<short>();
}
```

**Or** even better, initialize the empty list and add to it.

```
List<short> k = new List<short>();
if (filter != null)
{
    k.Add(filter.Value);
}
```

**But**, Keep in mind that `(short) t.SalesStatusID` will give you unexpected results. What if you `SalesStatusID` value is a number which is bigger than `short.MaxValue`(**32767**) ?  So i suggest use the same type and avoiding the casting.

```
List<int> k = new List<int>();  //Assuming SalesStatusID's type is int32
if (filter != null)
{
    k.Add(filter.Value);
}
else
{
    k = _db.SalesStatus.Select(a=>a.SaleStatusID).ToList();
}
// use k now
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning k (which is a List type) to value of filter (which is nullable short type) You need to change your else statement to this

```
else
{
    k.Add(filter.Value);
}
```